# Do SharePoint Permissions Transfer to Word Documents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, permissions

I was trying to remember if the permissions on a user extend to attachments on list items?  Part of me wants to say yes on this but I am having a hard time searching for the answer.  If no, is there a way to make the attachments in a SharePoint list item read only?  Can I attach direct permissions from SharePoint to the attached documents?  Thanks!

Comment: Can't say I'm 100% sure, but the attachments are stored in the SPListItem object, I believe, so I'd lean to yes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SharePoint permissions, down to the item-level will apply to the attachments of a list item.  Attachments are stored in a special folder within the List (appropriately called Attachments).  They are placed in a sub-folder of the attachments list with the ID of the associated list item as the folder name.  For instance: http:// site/List/Attachments/1/File.docx (List = list name, Attachments = special folder, 1 = ID of list item).  The permissions for the "1" folder are directly associated with the permissions of the list item with that ID.

Comment: Excellent!  This is what I figured.  I am coming up to a situation in a new farm I am working in where this is going to come up A LOT!  Thanks for the confirmation.